# Unexpected behavior while typing on p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

Using PrimeFaces `<p:selectOneMenu>` component, if I have for example 3 values like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{buttonBean.number}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Astrid" itemValue="Astrid" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Banana" itemValue="Banana" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cards" itemValue="Cards" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

If I start typing "B", it selects the item Banana, but if I type "Ba", it selects Astrid because the last character is "a".
If I use the `<h:selectOneMenu>` it works as expected. This behavior happens only with the PrimeFaces component.

What should I do?

Comment: You should post it on the Primefaces-forum. Development is active on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

I try your case in primfaces 3.4 and did not reproduce your problem.When I typed "Ba"  it selects Banana not Astrid,the only difference is that my list is Dynamic not static one as in your example.